# How to open chatbot on webhook feed event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I subscribed my webhook to the 'feed' events, however. Is there any way to open the chatbot to the user that comments or do anything on the page?

Bearing in mind that I need to have a app scoped fb_id for that user to send messages to them.

Thanks.

Comment: The user has to start the conversation

Comment: @WizKid Check out this Manychat feature: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YWc_oF4BHU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

You can't exactly open the chatbot itself after a comment or post etc. What you can do is to `POST`"private_reply" to the user, then your chatbot webhook can monitor for any further messages.

To do so, you can use the following endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/object/private_replies